# MERN project | Heroku doesn't set client-side cookie

Tags: node.js, heroku, passport.js

My MERN project work well on my local but when I deployed it I get 401 error while fetching user. Heroku doesn't set client-side cookie. Then I  have searched on google first ı change my cookie-session to express-session and some other configuration and still, it doesn't work on Heroku.
https://github.com/olcaykaplan/passport_google

cors:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']

  })
);
```

express session:

```
    app.use(
  express.session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly:true,
      secure: true,
      maxAge: oneDay,
    },
  })
);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your client side work on local,
change  secure value to false, remove proxy and sameSite

The project was working fine with the following cors and session information

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "netlify url",
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']

  })
);
const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // Equals 1 day (1 day * 24 hr/1 day * 60 min/1 hr * 60 sec/1 min * 1000 ms / 1 sec)
app.use(cookieParser("secret"));
app.use(
  express.session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    proxy: true, 
    cookie: {
      sameSite:"none", 
      //path: "/",
      httpOnly:true,
      secure: true, 
      maxAge: oneDay,
    },
  })
);
```